# Angular2 Default value for select tag

Tags: angular, html-select

I'm trying to set a default value for my 'select' tag in angular2 according to a model

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div>
  <label>Agence: </label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="candidat.agence">
    <option *ngFor="let agence of agences" [ngValue]="agence">{{agence.nom}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

COMPONENT

```
export class CandidatDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    candidat: Candidat;

    agences: Agence[];

    constructor(
        private agenceService: AgenceService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.agenceService.getAgences().then(agences => this.agences = agences);
    }
}
```

AGENCE

```
export class Agence {
    id: number;
    nom: string;
}
```

CANDIDAT

```
export class Candidat {
    id: number;
    nom: string;
    agence: Agence;
}
```

The candidat attributes is retrieved from another component

When the div is displayed, the default value `agence.nom` is not set

Does someone have an idea ? Thanks !!!

Comment: If you could show us the data of `candidat` and `agences` it would be easier to help you. Also, the `<select>` must contain the `name` *attribute*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `select` must have `name` *attribute*:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="candidat.agence" name="WHATEVER">
```

Based on the `code` shown, the bind should happens automatically... maybe the `candidat.agence` has *some* property different from `agence` (of `agences` *array*).

Anyway, to set the `candidat`, you can do this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.agenceService.getAgences().then(agences => this.agences = agences);

  if (this.candidat && this.candidat.agence) {
    this.candidat.agence = this.agences.find(agence => agence.name === this.candidat.agence.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an ugly workaround:

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.candidat) {
        for (let agence of this.agences) {
            if (this.candidat.agence.nom == agence.nom) {
                this.candidat.agence = agence;
            }
        }
}
```

This set the agence of the candidat to an object defined in the list

Is there a cleaner way to do it ?

Comment: Put a `console.log` in `ngOnInit` and compare `this.candidat.agence` with the `objects` inside the `array` to see what's different..

Comment: They have same ID and NAME, I don't know what is different. Thanks for your answer, it works as well as mine :)

Comment: So, it's impossible that the bind doesn't work automatically, I suggest you to create a plunker and link it here, so I can take a look.